# How to put slideshow indicators to the top left

Tags: html, css

I have got a basic slideshow, but i wish to put the indicators to the top left of the slides, but nothing is working.

I have tried margins, padding and even searched the internet and on here for a solution, but still nothing

CODE:

```css
.carousel{
 position:relative
}
.carousel-inner{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height: 690px;
 overflow:hidden
}
.carousel-inner>.item{
 position:relative;
 display:none;
 -webkit-transition:.6s ease-in-out left;
 -o-transition:.6s ease-in-out left;
 transition:.6s ease-in-out left
}
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img,.carousel-inner>.item>img{
 line-height:1
}
@media all and (transform-3d),(-webkit-transform-3d){
 .carousel-inner>.item
 {
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:-o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
  transition:-webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
  transition:transform .6s ease-in-out;
  transition:transform .6s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out,-o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-perspective:1000px;
  perspective:1000px
 }
 .carousel-inner>.item.active.right,.carousel-inner>.item.next{
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(100%,0,0);
  transform:translate3d(100%,0,0);
  left:0
 }
 .carousel-inner>.item.active.left,.carousel-inner>.item.prev{
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0);
  transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0);
  left:0
 }
 .carousel-inner>.item.active,.carousel-inner>.item.next.left,.carousel-inner>.item.prev.right{
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  left:0
 }
}
.carousel-inner>.active,.carousel-inner>.next,.carousel-inner>.prev{
 display:block
}
.carousel-inner>.active{
 left:0
}
.carousel-inner>.next,.carousel-inner>.prev{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 width:100%
}
.carousel-inner>.next{
 left:100%
}
.carousel-inner>.prev{
 left:-100%
}
.carousel-inner>.next.left,.carousel-inner>.prev.right{
 left:0
}
.carousel-inner>.active.left{
 left:-100%
}
.carousel-inner>.active.right{
 left:100%
}
.carousel-control{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 width:15%;
 font-size:20px;
 color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
 filter:alpha(opacity=50);
 opacity:.5
}
.carousel-control.left{
 background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 100%);
 background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 100%);
 background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(rgba(0,0,0,.5)),to(rgba(0,0,0,.0001)));
 background-image:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', 
  GradientType=1);
 background-repeat:repeat-x
}
.carousel-control.right{
 right:0;
 left:auto;
 background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
 background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
 background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(rgba(0,0,0,.0001)),to(rgba(0,0,0,.5)));
 background-image:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', 
  GradientType=1);
 background-repeat:repeat-x
}
.carousel-control:focus,.carousel-control:hover{
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 outline:0;
 filter:alpha(opacity=90);
 opacity:.9
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
.carousel-control .icon-next,.carousel-control .icon-prev{
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 z-index:5;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-top:-10px
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,.carousel-control .icon-prev{
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-10px
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,.carousel-control .icon-next{
 right:50%;
 margin-right:-10px
}
.carousel-control .icon-next,.carousel-control .icon-prev{
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
 font-family:serif;
 line-height:1
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev:before{
 content:"\2039"
}
.carousel-control .icon-next:before{
 content:"\203a"
}
.carousel-indicators{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:10px;
 left:100px;
 z-index:15;
 width:60%;
 padding-left:0;
 margin-left:-30%;
 margin-top:-30%;
 text-align:center;
 list-style:none
}
.carousel-indicators li{
 display:inline-block;
 width:10px;
 height:10px;
 margin:1px;
 text-indent:-999px;
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color:#000\9;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
 border:1px solid #fff;
 border-radius:10px
}
.carousel-indicators .active{
 margin-top: 250px;
 width:12px;
 height:12px;
 margin:0;
 background-color:#fff
}
.carousel-caption{
 position:absolute;
 right:15%;
 bottom:20px;
 left:15%;
 z-index:10;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6)
}
.carousel-caption h3{
 float:left;
 margin-left:-350px;
 background-color:#fff;
 padding: 7px 20px 5px;
 color:#000
}
.carousel-caption .btn{
 text-shadow:none
}
.show{
 margin-top: 240px;
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: none
}
```

```html
<div class="container show">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/46e3dd55b6cc4f1df004cabd85cbaac6fc8e1218.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/black.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chicago</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/46e3dd55b6cc4f1df004cabd85cbaac6fc8e1218.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>New York</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot for indication:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAeok.jpg

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

We are unsetting the Bottom position, setting the top position to 10px and then removing the margin-top: style.

```
    .carousel-indicators{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:10px;
        left:100px;
        z-index:15;
        width:60%;
        padding-left:0;
        margin-left:-30%;
        margin-top:-30%;
        text-align:center;
        list-style:none
    }
```

With this

```
    .carousel-indicators{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:unset;
        top: 10px;
        left:100px;
        z-index:15;
        width:60%;
        padding-left:0;
        margin-left:-30%;
        text-align:center;
        list-style:none
    }
```

An example can be found here:

https://codepen.io/CTBroon/pen/xxKOreE

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Can you look at the example codepen?

It's hard to work out without the full repo you have, do you have a link I can look at or somewhere I can see the code rather than in a screenshot?

Comment: I looked at the codepen and figured out the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer which will also close the question :)